# Matplotlib plot for loop issue

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot time series data in matplotlib using a for loop.  The goal is to dynamically plot 'n' years worth of daily closing price data.  If i load 7 years of data, I get 7 unique plots.  I have created a summary of the start and end dates for a data set, yearly_date_ranges (date is the index).  I use this to populate start and end dates.  The code I've written so far produces 7 plots of all daily data instead of 7 unique plots, one for each year.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
    yearly_date_ranges
              start        end
    Date                      
    2014 2014-04-01 2014-12-31
    2015 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
    2016 2016-01-01 2016-12-31
    2017 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
    2018 2018-01-01 2018-12-31
    2019 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
    2020 2020-01-01 2020-05-28

    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,20))
    for i in range(len(yearly_date_ranges)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(yearly_date_ranges),1,i + 1)       
        for row in yearly_date_ranges.itertuples(index=False):
            start = row.start
            end = row.end
            subset = data[start:end]        
            ax.plot(subset['Close'])

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically you should do something like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(7,1, figsize=(12,20))

years = data.index.year

for ax, (k,d) in zip(axes.ravel(), data.groupby(years)):
    d.plot(y='Close', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks, this generated 7 plots of all columns in data, not just 'Close'.  It looks like it is by year just full of additional rows.   Digging into this more now.

Comment: I changed data.groupby(years)):  to data['Close'].groupby(years)):  and it worked!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, my code would also work if it were `y='Close'` as edited.

Answer (score 0):

This worked!  Thank you for the help

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(7,1, figsize=(12,20))

    years = data.index.year

    for ax, (k,d) in zip(axes.ravel(), data['Close'].groupby(years)):
        d.plot(x='Close', ax=ax)
```